# How to use JQuery Marquee in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using `<marquee>` in my homepage , I want to use [jquery marquee](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/) instead , I've added script in my header , in usage it says i have to use  `$('marquee').marquee(optionalClass);` , how and where i have to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress comes with copy of jQuery bundled. See `wp_enqueue_script()` documentation for how to:

1. Register you script properly and make it load jQuery as dependency
2. Use required noConflict wrapper so you can use jQUery functions (simply `$` won't work in WP).

Comment: Thanks , I've added following code and jquery marquee is working now :
`<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://mysite.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.marquee.js">
</script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('marquee').marquee();
});
</script>`